# basic questions in swing components in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

my question is could be very basic in terms of understanding this simple code. I wrote this code myself grabbing bits of code from here and there to understand. I would like to actually follow this code line by line as to what each line means?
I have added my understanding as comments above the line of code, it could be wrong or some of them marked as `****` means I just dont know what it means. If you could help me out here, it will be great.
Thanks

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestingSwingComponents {

    public TestingSwingComponents() {
        //Create a frame which is the window that pops up
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
        //*****
        myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //set the frame size to be 600 X 600 size
        myframe.setSize(600, 600);

        // create Pane1
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        //set the Layout component of Panel, as how you would like it to be
        //here it is 2 rows and 15 columns
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 15));
        //create a button with text in it
        JButton letterButton = new JButton("click Me");
        //add the created button component to the panel
        myPanel.add(letterButton);
        //******
        myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // create another panel
        JPanel panelFormat = new JPanel();
        //create a textfield
        JTextField txtfield = new JTextField();
        //create a label for the textfield
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
        //set the layout type for this panel
        panelFormat.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //add label to panel
        panelFormat.add(label);
        //add textfield to panel
        panelFormat.add(txtfield);
        //I dont know the difference between the below two
        //BorderLayout.CENTER still does not center the panel in the frame, I dont know why
        myframe.getContentPane().add(panelFormat, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myframe.add(panelFormat);

        // default settings
        myframe.setTitle("Get buttons");
        myframe.setVisible(true);
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        new TestingSwingComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swing tutorial does a good job of explaining these concepts. You've been given links below. I suggest you take a look at the table of contents and bookmark that link for future reference. Not only that the examples from the tutorial will show you the proper way to create a GUI by making sure all code executes on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You can find out more about the EDT by reading the section on "Concurrency".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

To answer this, you need to understand the structure of a Swing window.  A `JFrame` (in fact any Swing window) is made up a series of components which generate the view of the window.

[image]

(Picture from [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html))

A `JRootPane` makes up the base of view, on-top of which is a `JLayeredPane` and what is know as the "glass pane".  The `JLayeredPane` is responsible for managing the `JMenuBar` and the "content pane".

The content pane is where you components reside on the window.

So, what this line is saying is, *"get the frame's content pane and set it's layout to use a `BorderLayout`"*

The layouts API is an entire question on it's own and it would be use to you to have a read through [Laying out components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for a more indeepth description, but basically, layout managers remove the need for you to care (a greate deal) about differences in rendering techniques employeed by different systems...

```
//******
myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This comes back to the layout manager.  Because you can have any number of layout managers, Swing allows you to pass a "constraint" to the layout manager when you add the component, giving the layout manager some idea of how you might like this component to be added.

If you take a closer look at [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) you will see that it has five positions in which components can be added.

[image]

The line is basically saying, *"please add `myPanel` to the `SOUTH` position within the frame/content pane"*

**Update from comments**

If you have a look at this snippet...

```
panelFormat.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//add label to panel
panelFormat.add(label);
//add textfield to panel
panelFormat.add(txtfield);
```

It sets the layout manager for `panelFormat` to `BorderLayout`.  `BorderLayout` can only have a single component in any of it's five available positions.  When you use `add(Component)` without passing it a layout constraint, `BorderLayout` use `CENTER` as the default position, this means you are trying to add two components to the `CENTER` position, this is not possible, so `BorderLayout` simply uses the last component that was added.

> why not borderlayout fix the size of textfield instead of stretching
>   it all window

Because this is how `BorderLayout` works and no, `GridLayout` would probably do something simular.

You could try `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout`

**Updated from comments**

You seriously need to take the time to read through the linked (and other suggested) tutorials...but basically, you can use a `GridBagLayout` just like any other layout, you create an instance of it and apply it to the container...

[image]

```
// create another panel
JPanel panelFormat = new JPanel();
//create a textfield
JTextField txtfield = new JTextField(10);
//create a label for the textfield
JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
//set the layout type for this panel
panelFormat.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
//add label to panel
panelFormat.add(label);
//add textfield to panel
panelFormat.add(txtfield);
//I dont know the difference between the below two
//BorderLayout.CENTER still does not center the panel in the frame, I dont know why
myframe.getContentPane().add(panelFormat, BorderLayout.CENTER);
myframe.add(panelFormat);
```

Comment: Thanks, why `myframe.getContentPane().add(panelFormat, BorderLayout.CENTER);` this line did not center the panel containing Labels and textfield?

Comment: Because `myPanel` is under the control of a `GridLayout`, which has it's own concept of how components should be laid it.  The above line will ensure that the panel is placed in the center position of the frame, allowing it to grow and shrink with the frame

Comment: sorry, if you execute this code, you will notice that the label is not seen and the textfield occupies entire frame. to squeeze its size, do I have to use GridLayout again? why not borderlayout fix the size of textfield instead of stretching it all window

Comment: huh..I wanted to have label and textfield in center of frame and of small size. so is it not possible to have both of them in center using `BorderLayout.CENTER`. and for regarding size, do I have to use GridbagLayout?

Comment: Thank you. I will read through the docs. But your answers clarifies most part. now reading will make it easier :)

Answer (score 3):

A Swing top-level container, including a JFrame, JDialog is composed of several components all held together including a JRootPane which holds all together, a JLayeredPane, and a contentPane the latter of which holds most of the GUI excepting the top window bar. You can read more about the details in this tutorial here: [Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html):

[image]

[image]

So when you add a component to a JFrame in a default way, you're actually adding it to its contentPane. In other words, this:

```
myJFrame.add(myComponent);
```

is functionally the same as this:

```
myJFrame.getContentPane().add(myComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning Swing, I used this great tutorial which goes over everything you have, and explains it pretty clearly in depth.

The tutorial also goes over the elements that you are having trouble understanding.

[Here is said tutorial.](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/)